# How to use DELETE ON CASCADE in this senario?

Tags: sql, ddl

so I have 3 tables, Applicant, Vacancy and a Link table. I am trying to have the applicant data removed when the vacancy is removed. Here is the current SQL code I have, would this remove the applicant?

```
CREATE TABLE Applicant(
  ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(20),
  address varchar(20),
  VacancyID INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (VacancyID) REFERENCES Vacancy(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE);


CREATE TABLE AppVac(
             ApplicantID INT PRIMARY KEY,
             VacancyID INT PRIMARY KEY,
             FOREIGN KEY (ApplicantID) REFERENCES Applicant(ID),
             FOREIGN KEY (VacancyID) REFERENCES Vacancy(ID);

CREATE TABLE Vacancy(
             ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
             .....
```

Comment: Post code about what you tried and we can help you

Comment: I have posted the SQL of creating the three tables. What I am trying to accomplish is when the vacancy is removed the applicant's data is also removed. The applicants are linked to the vancancy via the link table (AppVac)

Answer (score 0):

No.  The `Applicant` has not relationship to the `Vacancy`.  What gets removed are all corresponding rows in `AppVac`.

If you want to require that applicants have at least one row in `AppVac`, then you'll need a delete trigger on the table.  Cascading foreign keys won't do that for you.  That is, cascading deletes delete from the *referring* table, not from the *reference* table.